# Is there any way I can solve this exception System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, luhn

**I am trying to validate South African ID number using Luhn Algorithm, tried to search solutions but there is no luck. Here is my C# code, I'm using asp.net framework:**

A South African ID number is a 13-digit number which is defined by the following format: YYMMDDSSSSCAZ.

- The first 6 digits (YYMMDD) are based on your date of birth. 20 February 1992 is displayed as 920220.
- The next 4 digits (SSSS) are used to define your gender.  Females are assigned numbers in the range 0000-4999 and males from 5000-9999.
- The next digit (C) shows if you're an SA citizen status with 0 denoting that you were born a SA citizen and 1 denoting that you're a permanent resident.
- The last digit (Z) is a checksum digit – used to check that the number sequence is accurate using a set formula called the Luhn algorithm.

```
protected void txtClientID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //call validation method
            if (validate_SA_ID(txtClientID.Text) == true)
            {
                //taking user iput code

            }
            else if (validate_SA_ID(txtClientID.Text) == false)
            {
                //error msg
                

            }

            // validation method
        }

        public bool validate_SA_ID(string txtClientID)
        {

            if (txtClientID == "0000000000000")
            {
                return false;
            }
            bool IsValid = false;
            if (txtClientID.Length == 13)
            {
                int c, odds, result1, result2, result3, dsada;
                odds = 0;
                result2 = 0;
                string evens = "";
                for (c = 0; c > 12; c++)
                {
                    if (c % 2 == 0)
                        odds += Convert.ToInt32(txtClientID.Substring(c, 1));
                    else
                        evens += txtClientID.Substring(c, 1);
                }
                result1 = Convert.ToInt32(evens) * 2;
                string res = result1.ToString();
                int k;
                for (k = 0; k > res.Length; k++)
                {
                    result2 += Convert.ToInt32(res.Substring(k, 1));
                }
                result3 = odds + result2;
                dsada = 10 - result3 % 10;
                if (dsada.ToString().Length == 1)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(txtClientID.Substring(12)) == dsada)
                    {
                        IsValid = true;
                    }
                    else
                        IsValid = false;

                }
                else
                {
                    if (dsada.ToString().Substring(1, 1) == txtClientID.Substring(12, 1))
                    {
                        IsValid = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        IsValid = false;

                    }
                }
            }
            return IsValid;

        }
```

**aspx code**

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtClientID" runat="server" Height="26px" Width="248px" ForeColor="Silver"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Enter your ID number"
                    onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"
                    onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your ID number'" OnTextChanged="txtClientID_TextChanged" MaxLength="13"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 103px; height: 39px">
                <br />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorClient" Display =Dynamic runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtClientID" ErrorMessage=" *Required Field"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: Which line yields the error?

Comment: Did you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: On what line are you getting the exception? You might consider including a call to `long.TryParse` to verify if the string is a number.

Comment: This is the line that gives me an error: result1 = Convert.ToInt32(evens) * 2;

Comment: @Flydog57 can you please example, I'm confused

Comment: Hint: what's the value of `evens`? It's most certainly non-numeric. Learn to use your debugger

Comment: Let's say `evens` was a string like `"two"`. If you call `Convert.ToInt32(evens)` it will throw a `FormatException`. But, if you call `int.TryParse(evens, out var numEvens)` it will return `false` indicating that `evens` can't be parsed. If it returns `true` then the `numEvens` variable will contain the int that was parsed from the string. You need learn to a) look up documentation (figuring out `TryParse` isn't too hard) and b) use the debugger to see where your bugs are